# How to avoid parametrization of a Pytest class when skipping it?

Tags: python, pytest, lazy-evaluation, parametrize

I have two Pytest classes: one test class is very fast and the other is slower, parametrizing itself with a function call and reusing that resource across multiple tests.

My problem is that, when running the quicker test via `pytest test.py -k "Quick"`, I have to wait for the slower test to be parametrized before the specified test will be run.

```py
class TestQuick:
    def test_quick(self): pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize('num', get_nums())
class TestSlow
    def test_1(self, num): pass
    def test_2(self, num): pass

def get_nums():
    inputs = range(100)
    with multiprocess.Pool(10) as pool:
        return list(pool.map(IO_fn, # takes a lot of time
                             inputs))
```

I have tried using `@pytest.mark.parametrize('num', get_nums(), indirect=True`), but I couldn't get this to work.

I also tried using `@pytest.fixture(scope='class')` on `IO_fn`, which is *almost there* except for:

1. I lose the crucial ability to speed up collection of `nums` using multiprocessing.
2. I want my test output to be grouped by `TestSlow/num/test` rather than just a flat directory of `TestSlow/test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit "dirty" hack to parse input arguments and stop executing long process when it meets `Quick` tag:

```
import sys
import pytest


def get_nums():
    if sys.argv[-1] == 'Quick':
        return []
    inputs = range(100)
    with multiprocess.Pool(10) as pool:
        return list(pool.map(IO_fn, inputs))


class TestQuick:
    def test_quick(self): pass


@pytest.mark.parametrize('num', get_nums())
class TestSlow:
    def test_1(self, num): pass

    def test_2(self, num): pass
```

Testing:

`pytest test.py -k "Quick"` — runs fast

`pytest test.py -k "Slow"` — runs slow